# Test flight app could not install error

Tags: ios, xcode, testflight

I uploaded build in test flight
when i try to download "The app could not install because the developer's certificate is no longer valid.To resolve the issue, contact developer".

Answer (score 0):

It simply means that the developer account from which this app is uploaded is expired OR the development/distribution certificates of the app are expired or revoked. It can be resolved by activating the certificates of the app on apple's developer portal.

Hope this helps...

Comment: i double checked certificates are active.Recreating all certificates fixed issue